# How to stop my program from freezing up with TCP connection C#

Tags: c#, tcp

I have created a TCP client and it connects fine but am a bit confused how to receive messages from the server without closing the connection ?

My current approach was to run a co-routine over the network stream read method but that freezes my program up so its obviously the wrong approach so am not sure how to fix it.

I want to keep the connection alive and read messages when ever they may arrive from the server.

This is what i have setup currently:

```
// the idea is to run a coroutine for recieving messages
private IEnumerator<float> _RunTCPSocket()
{
    int timer = DateTime.Now.Second;
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];

    while (SocketManager.IsConnected)
    {
        // this is the keep alive packets to server to prevent timeout on server side
        if (DateTime.Now.Second - timer > KeepAliveRate)
        {
            Debug.Log("Sending");
            timer = DateTime.Now.Second;
            SocketManager.Send(null);
        }

        int msgLength = SocketManager.Recieve(readBuffer); 
        if (msgLength > 0)
            Debug.Log(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer, 0, msgLength));

        yield return Timing.WaitForOneFrame;
    }
}
```

This is the code for the receive method:

```
    public int Recieve(byte[] readBuffer)
    {
        if (!IsConnected)
            return -1; //-1 signifies an error aka we are disconnected

        try
        {
            // NetworkStream is from TcpClient.GetStream()
            bytesRead = _networkStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            IsConnected = false;
            Debug.Log(e);
            bytesRead = -1;
        }

        return bytesRead;
    }
```

How do i prevent this  from locking up my program ?

Comment: You must do network stuff in another Thread or use the async functions to read, send and connect, listen to the network or these functions will block until something(error/success) happens.

Comment: you must use BackgroundWorker https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Hmm i looked at the Async methods but no examples were given, the only TCP Client example they had was a synchronous one.

Comment: There are few example of `Async` out there but use `ThreadPool`. This will separate your network code from your application code. You can build a wrapper with this that calls an event when there is a new data received. Just subscribe to do.

Comment: I've got a basic Async setup now without Thread pools at the moment. Thats on my to do list. But if i want to receive messages from a server on a persistent TCP connection, how exactly does that work with Async? I tried a coroutine but not sure if this `private async IEnumerator<float> _RecieveMessages()` is the right design for such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Begin/End method to make your program responsible:

[Document from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceive?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.1)

You can see that the using of `BeginReceive` method is so complex so personally, i don't think it's easy to use.
An alternative is to call the read/write method inside a Task.
The third option is use `TcpClient` which used on client side and `TcpListener` which used on server side. Those two class is just a wrapper for an underline TCP socket. Those wrapper can make your life much more easier with Stream and Async methods.

If you want to learn more about network programming with C#, i highly recomment this book: 
 **C# Network Programming** by **Richard Blum**

**Update**

Code for working with Task:

```
    public event EventHandler<ReceiveDataEventArgs> DataReceived = null;
    public void StartReceive()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var bytesRead = _networkStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                DataReceived?.Invoke(this, new ReceiveDataEventArgs
                {
                    Data = bytesRead
                });
            }
        });

    }

    public class ReceiveDataEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I currently am using Read in a task but how do i keep checking frequently if new messages arrive from the server and handle them ? Thats something i cannot find good code examples of using tasks.

Comment: With the client code which only receive data, you can put your Read method inside a infinity loop which inside a Task. Once receive the data, just raise an event and other class which use your client class can subscribe to that event and handle the received data.

Comment: I have update code sample for working with task. I haven't working with socket for years so my code may have few syntax problem, but i'm sure that it should make your program responsible.